Extending next.config.js
I have 2 next.config.js files that I would like to combine.  I just don't understand how to combine them.
This next.config.js file has logic that seems useful
const { PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER } = require('next/constants');

module.exports = (phase) => {
  if (phase === PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER) {
    return {
      env: {
        mongodb_username: 'maxxxxxan',
        mongodb_password: '2YkxxxxPk0vqp',
        mongodb_clustername: 'cluster0',
        mongodb_database: 'my-site-dev',
      },

    };
  }

  return {
    env: {
      mongodb_username: 'maxxxxxn',
      mongodb_password: '2YkxxxxxxPk0vqp',
      mongodb_clustername: 'cluster0',
      mongodb_database: 'my-site',
    },
  };
};

This next.config.js file has the logic I currently need to use sqlite in my dev environment. Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in Next.js application
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig

